# Bit banging synchronous serial protocol on SAME70

Tags: cortex-m, atmel-studio, bit-bang, clock-recovery

I am trying to implement synchronous Serial protocol with SAME70 using board SAME70-XPLD. For that I need to generate clock of 2MHz. For that I am using TC module running at MCK/8 = 18.75MHz (MCK set to 150MHz), configured in compare mode. At each compare interrupt I update data and clock lines. I am not getting accurate timing results, Please suggest if bit banging with 2MHz clock is even possible or I am just wasting time?

Comment: That processor has several hardware UARTs on it, why are you trying to implement one in software?

Comment: Which synchronous serial protocol and why not the available harware peripherals can't be used?

Comment: @Sidk and what prevents using SPI for that?

Comment: @Justme Bit stuffing and idle detection needs bit banging right?

Comment: @Sidk you already do bit stuffing encoding/decoding in software so what would be the difference? And idle state is just continuous frame delimiter transmission/reception? Anyway, software interrupts at 2 MHz is usually very suspicious.

Comment: Presumably you could reconfigure when things turn around.  If you need to respond to an external clock, that's all the more reason to use a synchronous serial engine.  At some loss of efficiency, you could consider using DMA through a GPIO, but you'll probably end up with only one bit of meaning per byte (unless you treat the clock as sampled, too).